# Microsoft Teams Connector Configuration Save Failure

Tags: microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I'm working on creating a custom connector for Microsoft Teams.
I've created one based on the github tutorial repo. Everything is working fine but when I hit the save button nothing happens, seems like saveEvent.notifySuccess() is not working. I'm using React for the config page.

Any help will be appreciated.

Config Page MSTeam implementation:
[Config Page MSTeam implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktKe5.png)

Express server saveConfig:
[Express server saveConfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWSJV.png)

Screen after saving:
[Screen after saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24E5h.png)

```html
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.3/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.3",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "id": "23772851-b720-4f99-ae35-3531957cb1c7",
    "packageName": "com.demo.test",
    "developer": {
        "name": "Laxman Sharma",
        "websiteUrl": "https://www.google.com",
        "privacyUrl": "https://www.google.com/",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.google.com/"
    },
    "icons": {
        "color": "color.png",
        "outline": "outline.png"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "Test",
        "full": ""
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "Test Connector App",
        "full": "This app allows the team tp quickly do something."
    },
    "accentColor": "#40497E",
    "bots": [
        {
            "botId": "5e55cea4-4efc-4eec-9156-c6aa78b1622c",
            "scopes": [
                "personal",
                "team"
            ],
            "supportsFiles": false,
            "isNotificationOnly": true
        }
    ],
    "connectors": [
        {
            "connectorId": "f1014037-dad1-4da2-83af-479708155849",
            "configurationUrl": "https://e48f6f19.ngrok.io/",
            "scopes": [
                "team"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "validDomains": [
        "e48f6f19.ngrok.io"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please confirm if contentUrl value is added in valid domains section in Connector Portal? Please share you manifest so that we could test it at our end.

Comment: I was using ngrok for testing and added the domain in valid domains. Still does not work. I've added manifest.json as well. Please share if there's any problem.

Comment: Did you add the same in Connector Portal as well?

Comment: Yeah it's the same. I am able to see the configuration page when i try to configure connector using the same URL but the save button doesn't work. It times out after some time. I am only sending back like status 200 after saving configuration and using microsoftTeams.notifySuccess(). Is this the correct way to use?

Comment: Seems like your ngrok tunnel expired. Could you please setup new and share updated URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issues at the start, as Wajeed already mentioned please double check that:

- You are only using domains that are within valid domain list in
  manifest
- You also need to have the same urls set in Connector Portal
- Double check you're really using the connector you want to use

Comment: Thanks for sharing these. I've checked all three points still does not work.

Comment: did you check the dev tools? When my stuff wasn't working i had quite a few errors in chrome console saying i had wrong payload or the domain was invalid or something similar. 

It always failed for the window.microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings() call and gave me an error

Comment: Which dev tool are you referring to? When side loading in teams how does one access debugging tools?

Comment: Your browser dev tools show console errors for apps

Comment: Have been stuck at this thing for the last 1 day.
Tried making different connectors on the dashboard and listed all the used domains. Still throwing this weird error.

Comment: Still broken, experiencing the same issue. Creating a brand new connector in connector dashboard didn't resolve the issue either.